# Error installing paramiko using pip

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to install paramiko using pip. It shows the following long list of error messages after installation. The message here [Details here](http://pastebin.com/nquvaGLs).

Running pip freeze show the paramiko package on the installation list but it is not working.

Trying to run a simple paramiko program shows following error again

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paramikoBasic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/scripttest/paramiko_test/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/scripttest/paramiko_test/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backendsled
```

I even tried to install cryptography separately but that even didn't solve the problem. Installed **libffi** too but that also didn't work out.

Comment: Refer - https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi/issues/14

Comment: went through everything on that page ,

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using ubuntu since it's a common problem
The `cffi` module is dependent on `libffi` and `libffi-dev`.

If you search for current version using

`apt-cache search libffi`

you should be able to get latest version.

Currently you can install as
`sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev`

Also you need to install `python-dev` and crypto packages as logs indicates.

Credit: https://gist.github.com/tchalvak/a230f8b759875748240d

Cheers

Comment: Though this is the exact problem I have, but the solutions didn't work in my case.

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung can you update us on the progress you made?

Comment: installed libffi6 ,libffi-dev ,python-dev and cryptopackage but still the same error exist